# Thread was being aborted 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, webforms

What my code do is to search in the database a URL writing a parameter as you can see below. So when I return the URL and opened without the user click the hyperlink the error say: Thread was being aborted.

I save the url in a datatype string so using Response Redirect I want to open the page.

```
public void Consultar()
        {
            try
            {
                string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dba"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
                conexion.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying
                //     the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spBuscarUrl", conexion);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows
                //    to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add parameter to command, which
                //    will be passed to the stored procedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CodigoContrato", TextBox1.Text));
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    this.HyperLink1.Text = rdr["URL"].ToString();

                }

                string hyperLink = this.HyperLink1.Text;
                if(hyperLink != "")
                {
                    Response.Redirect(hyperLink);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Hubo error en la consulta')</script>");
               throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect(hyperLink, false);` - Go read up on why `Response.Redirect` always throw this exception.

Comment: Thanks. I already resolved it using that line of code. @Equalsk

Comment: As long as you understand what it actually does then no problem :-)